# How do I declare NaN (not a number) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, nan

Also "NaN".to_f returns 0 instead of NaN.

Comment: **tl;dr**: The spelling is all the difference, you have to write it all caps like `Float::NAN`.

Answer (score 52):

Since Ruby 1.9.3 there is a [constant](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#NAN) to get the NaN value

```
Float::NAN
=> NaN
```

Comment: That constant is actually available since [1.9.2](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS-1.9.2#L87).

Comment: This is much more expressive than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 31):

If you need to test if a number is NaN, you can use `#nan?` on it:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :008 > (0/0.0).nan? #=> true 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :009 > (0/1.0).nan? #=> false
```

Comment: Attention: `.nan?` only exists for Float: `undefined method \`nan?' for 100:Integer`. If you don't care what type of `number` your `value` is, use `if (0/0.0) == Float::NAN # then ...` instead.

Answer (score 17):

The simplest way is to use `0.0 / 0.0`.  "NaN".to_f doesn't work, and there's some discussion [in this thread](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/116271) about why.

Answer (score 3):

`0.0 / 0.0` works for me on ruby 1.8.6.

[The thread linked to by Pesto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/808687/4575793) has this function, which should work on platforms where floating-point numbers are implemented according to IEEE 754:

```
def aNaN
    s, e, m = rand(2), 2047, rand(2**52-1)+1
    [sprintf("%1b%011b%052b", s,e,m)].pack("B*").unpack("G").first
end
```

Comment: that gives ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Note: 0/0 gives a ZeroDivisionError, but 0.0 / 0.0 does not.

Comment: Attention: `if value == 0.0/0.0 # then ...` didn't work as expected. Use `if value == Float::NAN # then ...` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a variable in Rails can be done thus (useful for unit-testing):

```
o.amount = BigDecimal.new('NaN')
expect(o.valid?).to be false
```

Comment: Note that starting with `ruby-2.6.x` (as of 2018), `BigDecimal` becomes deprecated: `YOUR_RVM_RUBY_DIR/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_inclusion_of_matcher.rb:273: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.`